# android-plot bar chart from mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio

I need a solution for this problem. Currently I had follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBGdWPBdfPo&t=104s. I need to plot using my own data. I already save the data from mysql to php but I do not know how to display the data in my android studio. Please help me.
This is my php code:

```html
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

//checking if any error occured while connecting
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}

//creating a query
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT AVG(rb_fd),AVG(rb_check_in),AVG(rb_check_out),AVG(rb_room),AVG(rb_staff),AVG(rb_navigation),AVG(rb_fs),AVG(rb_decor),AVG(rb_facilities),AVG(rb_wifi) FROM rating;");

//executing the query
$stmt->execute();

//binding result to the query
$stmt->bind_result($rb_fd,$rb_check_in,$rb_check_out,$rb_room,$rb_staff,$rb_navigation,$rb_fs,$rb_decor,$rb_facilities,$rb_wifi);

$rating = array();

//traversing throung all the result
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $temp = array();
    $temp['FD'] = $rb_fd;
    $temp['CI'] = $rb_check_in;
    $temp['CO'] = $rb_check_out;
    $temp['R'] = $rb_room;
    $temp['S'] = $rb_staff;
    $temp['N'] = $rb_navigation;
    $temp['FS'] = $rb_fs;
    $temp['D'] = $rb_decor;
    $temp['F'] = $rb_facilities;
    $temp['W'] = $rb_wifi;
    array_push($rating, $temp);
}

//displaying the result in json format
echo json_encode($rating);

?>
```

This is the output when I check at Postman:

```html
[
    {
        "FD": 2.5,
        "CI": 2.5,
        "CO": 2.6666666666666665,
        "R": 2.5,
        "S": 3,
        "N": 3.3333333333333335,
        "FS": 3,
        "D": 2,
        "F": 3.5,
        "W": 3.6666666666666665
    }
]
```

This is my code in android studio.

```html
package com.example.user.hotelsuriamalaqaapp;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.Rating;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class AdminViewRating extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BarChart barChart;
    private BarData barData;
    private ListView rate;

    List<Rate2> ratingList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_view_rating);

        //This is code for bar chart
        barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barchart);
        barData = new BarData(getXvalues(), getBarValues());
        barData.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        barChart.setData(barData);
        barChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        barChart.getXAxis().setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        barChart.setDescription("Rating");

        barChart.setGridBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        barChart.animateXY(3000, 3000);
        barChart.invalidate();

        rate=findViewById(R.id.rate3);

        ratingList=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private ArrayList<BarDataSet> getBarValues() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, constant.URL_KIRA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
        ArrayList<BarDataSet> barDataSets;
        ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Rates");
        barDataSets = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            //converting the string to json array object
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("rating");

            //traversing through all the object
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                //getting product object from json array
                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                ratingList.add(new Rate2(
                        object.getString("FD"),
                        object.getString("CI"),
                        object.getString("CO"),
                        object.getString("R"),
                        object.getString("S"),
                        object.getString("N"),
                        object.getString("FS"),
                        object.getString("D"),
                        object.getString("F"),
                        object.getString("W")
                ));
                //barEntries.add(new BarEntry(rate,i);
            }

            barDataSet.setColor(Color.RED);
            barDataSets.add(barDataSet);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return barDataSets;
    }




    //This is coding for x axis
    private ArrayList<String> getXvalues(){
        ArrayList<String> xvalues = new ArrayList<>();
        xvalues.add("FD");
        xvalues.add("CI");
        xvalues.add("CO");
        xvalues.add("R");
        xvalues.add("S");
        xvalues.add("N");
        xvalues.add("FS");
        xvalues.add("D");
        xvalues.add("F");
        xvalues.add("W");

        return xvalues;
    }


}
```

Comment: you have gotten data to PHP. but PHP is running on your server. you need to present it in a format (e.g. JSON) so that you can fetch it from your android application via a http call, then you can display it.